# How to remove console error 422 (Unprocessable Content)

Tags: laravel

I write validation for email in my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

     /*
     * validate request
     */
    $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'unique:leads', 'email'],
    ]);

    return response()->json([],422);

    if (\App\Models\Lead::where(['email' => $request->get('email')])->count() > 0) {
        // user found
        return response()->json([ 'data' => [
            'message' => 'lindirizzo email è già registrato'
        ]], 200);

     }
    else {
        // Register the new user or whatever.
        $client = \App\Models\Lead::create(['email' => $request->get('email'),]);
        return response()->json([ 'data' => [
            'message' => 'Registrato con successo!'
        ]], 201);
    }
}
```

And  when i write the same email in front i get error POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/leads 422 (Unprocessable Content)

> My network respons its ok,
> {"message":"validation.unique","errors":{"email":["validation.unique"]}}
> But i dont want to show error in console

Comment: That should be the expected behaviour since you're trying to submit a *duplicate* Email. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: response does not appear as an error in the console

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73660350/edit) and show us the *"response in the console"* you're talking about?

Comment: My network respons its ok,
{"message":"validation.unique","errors":{"email":["validation.unique"]}}

But i dont want to show error in console

Comment: Okay, what would you want to happen instead?

Comment: Don't have this error console, just show the network response.

Comment: [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) errors are meant to guide the client/user about missing or incorrect HTTP request parameters. You should instead handle/display the errors *gracefully* on the client side. I.e: [Error 422 Ajax Post using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021074/7376590)

Comment: You can filter out network requests in a console if you don't want them to be shown, as long as an error is expected and handled

Comment: how can i filter out network requests in a console??

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is unnecessary.

```php
// ...
  return response()->json([],422);
// ...
```

Remove it.

---

[Writing The Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)

> ... if the validation fails, the proper response will automatically be
> generated. If the validation passes, our controller will continue
> executing normally.

---

##### Addendum

The block of code below is unnecessary as well since the validation rule `'unique:leads'` is sufficient:

```php
// ...
    if (\App\Models\Lead::where(['email' => $request->get('email')])->count() > 0) {
        // user found
        return response()->json([ 'data' => [
            'message' => 'lindirizzo email è già registrato'
        ]], 200);

     }
// ...
```

Remove it as well!

If you wish to have a custom message for the *"unique email"* validation, add it as the second parameter of the `->validate(...)` method:

```php
$request->validate([
    'email' => ['required', 'unique:leads', 'email'],
], [
    'email.unique' => 'lindirizzo email è già registrato'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you.
I remove it but error its the same in console "vendor.js:229          POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/leads 422 (Unprocessable Content)".

And in my network "{"message":"validation.unique","errors":{"email":["validation.unique"]}}"

Comment: How can i solve it??

Comment: my form.vue
  let form = new FormData();
 form.append("email", this.email);
 this.post("api/register/leads", form, this.handleMailResponse);


handleMailResponse: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                this.errors.push(response.data.data);
            } else {
                this.success.push(response.data.data);
            }

            this.$refs.form.reset();
        },

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check is there any email is available already or not in the table.
If you found any count of that email then simply ignore creating a record else you can add that email with a new entry inside the database.

```
if (Lead::where(['email' => $request->get('email')])->count() > 0) {
return response()->json([ 'data' => [
'message' => 'User data get successfully'
]], 200);

}else{
// Add a user with new email and send json response
}

}
```

Comment: You can give the right answer on this solution so that if other users have the same problem then they can easily find a solution.